# Android account removed in Safe Mode

Tags: android, accountmanager

I am having a problem where my app creates and account using the AccountManager and this account gets removed if the device is booted into safe mode. The account does not re-appear when the device is booted again in standard mode.

Is there any way to make my account so that it is not removed when the device is booted in safe mode?

To prove it wasn't something basic that I was doing wrong, I re-created a new sample app from scratch and it exhibits the same behaviour.

```
public static final String ACCOUNT_TYPE = "com.me.test";

Account account = new Account("test account", ACCOUNT_TYPE);
AccountManager.get(getApplicationContext())
    .addAccountExplicitly(account, null, null);
```

With authenticator.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<account-authenticator
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:accountType="com.me.test"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:smallIcon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/account_name"
    android:accountPreferences="@xml/account_preferences"
/>
```

Thanks

Comment: Would you like to show your Account creation code?

Comment: Sure, have added now

Comment: I'm afraid there is nothing you can do about that. Safe mode disables all 3rd party apps, including authenticators. However, the code that cleans up the account database still runs and removes all accounts that have no authenticator (which includes disabled authenticators too). We see the same issue with our apps.